# Unhandled promise rejection even though a catch handler exists

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, es6-promise

I have a ajax call like so

```
  const saveView = (name) => {
    let myWorkbook = tableauViz.getWorkbook()
    return myWorkbook.rememberCustomViewAsync(name)
  };


  const createDashboardShare = (dashboard_id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: `/dashboards/${dashboard_id}/dashboard_shares`,
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'POST',
        beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        },
        data: {
        },
        success: function(data) {
          resolve();
        },
        error: function(err) {
          reject(err);
        }
      });
    });
  };
```

I am using this in a chain of promises call like below (relevant code)

```
  const process = () => {
    saveView(name)
      .then((view) => createDashboardShare(dashboardId, view.getUrl(), viewName))
      .then(null, function(err) {

      });
  };
```

in case of rejection in `createDashboardShare` this is generating a `Unhandled promise exception` even though i have a catch defined.

Any help on why this is not working as expected will be great.

Comment: Where exactly is your catch clause in the code snippets you posted?

Comment: @GeorgiB.Nikolov - `.then(null,function(err) { ... })` is equivalent to catch

Comment: Could it be that `jQuery.ajax` returns a rejected promise even if you pass in success and error handlers? Try just returning `jQuery.ajax` instead of wrapping it in a promise. Also, what version of jQuery is this?

Comment: Thanks @Adam for your reply, i will try this. Jquery version is `1.12.4`

Comment: @Adam if i don't wrap it in a promise how can i forward the data to next in the chain

Comment: @opensource-developer, because jqXHR in 1.12 (which is what `jQuery.ajax` returns) supports a `then` method that accepts `onSuccess`, `onFail`, just like native promises - so you can actually just return it. While I recommend doing that, I don't think the 'unhandled promise exception' is actually coming from the code you have shown, at least not without providing further context (e.g. the code paths around it). I also feel like I've seen this code before on SO - did you have a similar question a while ago?